# GA4 detects the purchase event but does not add the total revenue

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

I have a project developed in angular and I am using angulartics2 to send the events to google analytics, all the events are detected and shown, however the total revenue shows 0.00€ any idea why?

It's been more than a week and still nothing....

The data being sent is as follows (print of chrome GTM/GA Debug extension)

[image]

Through google tag manager it is possible to check the datalayer (the data that was sent is different because it is a different order):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In GA4 there isn't `actionField` object in the script:

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
    transaction_id: "T_12345",
    affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
    value: 25.42,
    tax: 4.90,
    shipping: 5.99,
    currency: "USD",
    coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
    items: [
     {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      currency: "USD",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "L_12345",
      price: 9.99,
      quantity: 1
    },
      ...
```

Try to check your purchase code if like the example in Google Analytics 4 ecommerce documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#purchase

Comment: Removed actionfield but still doesn't add the total revenue